# python float a real number preserving significant digits even when are all are zero

Tags: python, floating-accuracy, digits

I have to plot i a figure some number with a specific number of significant digits even when all are zero. I mean, if I have a number like 12.00000000, I would like to print 12.000 and not 12.

This is what I have tried:
Given a number read from a file

```
a='23.00000000'
```

I convert it to float and I specify the number of digits as

```
 b = float(a)
float("{:.3f}".format(b))
```

However, this is the results:

```
Out[]: 23.0
```

while I would like to have

```
Out[]: 23.000
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line:

```
float("{:.3f}".format(b))
```

`"{:.3f}".format(23.0)` will give you `'23.000'`, but then you're converting it to float again, which removes the trailing 0's.

To correct it, you can do:

```
"{:.3f}".format(b)
```

and it will result in: `'23.000'`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the plotting part. You might be able to change the precision of the plot. However, I think you can use **format**:

Using format:

```
a = '23.00000000'
b = float(a)
b = format(b, '.3f')
```